# Prerender returning undefined:// with angular-meteor app

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor, prerender

I've removed spiderable package and added [prerender](https://atmospherejs.com/dfischer/prerenderio) package to my angular-meteor app.

```
{
  "public": {
  },
  "PrerenderIO": {
    "token": "mytoken"
  }
}
```

This is my settings.json file

[image: screenshot from 2016-03-04 09 40 39]

after the `undefined://` it's my ip address from the server.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Tried adding

```
"PrerenderIO": {
  "token": "mytoken"
}
```

to the `mup.json` file but still doesn't work.

Comment: This is on your server and not locally?  Are you sure the settings are being used by the server?

Comment: It's on a server in digital ocean, I'm using `meteor up` to deploy the app. My `settings.json` is at the root folder, but I'm not sure if that's the way to add the prerender configuration. Do I have to do something in the `mup.json` file?

Comment: I unfortunately don't know much about mup.  It looks like you're supposed to do a `mup init` and that will create a settings.json file for you.  Are you editing the one created for you?

Comment: ah, yes I have the mup.json file. I'll try adding the settings for prerender in there and test it.

Comment: I've tried adding the code to `mup.json` and deployed, but no luck, google fetch returns as unreachable and prerender returns 504 with that weird url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
"PrerenderIO": {
  "token": "mytoken",
  "host": "yourwebsite.com",
  "protocol": "https"
}
```

Change yourwebsite.com to your domain and set the protocol to http or https...whichever one your site supports.